# Navigating from component Button to Tab in TabView using NativeScript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a TabView set up like this in app.component.html:

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
        name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Game', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
        name="gameTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Courses', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
        name="coursesTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

Any my routing in app-routing.module.ts like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/(homeTab:home/default//gameTab:game/default//coursesTab:courses/default)",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    {
        path: "home",
        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
        loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule",
        outlet: "homeTab"
    },
    {
        path: "game",
        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
        loadChildren: "~/app/game/game.module#GameModule",
        outlet: "gameTab"
    },
    {
        path: "courses",
        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
        loadChildren: "~/app/courses/courses.module#CoursesModule",
        outlet: "coursesTab"
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now I wish to navigate from the `homeTab` by clicking a button in my `home.component.html`, so I try this:

```
<Button text="Add a course" (tap)="gotoCourses()" class="btn-green" width="50%"></Button>
```

An in my home.component.ts i try to navigate to the `/courses` path:

```
constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) { }

public gotoCourses(){
    this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/courses"]);
}
```

I have also tried with the paths:

```
courses
courses/default
//coursesTab
//coursesTab:courses
//coursesTab:courses/default
../coursesTab:courses/default
../coursesTab:courses
../coursesTab
../courses
../courses/default
```

But I get an error like:

```
S: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'courses'
JS: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'courses'
JS:     at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SimpleStats/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2557:20) [angular]
JS:     at CatchSubscriber.selector (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SimpleStats/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2538:33) [angular]
JS:     at CatchSubscriber.error (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SimpleStats/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/catchError.js:48:31) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SimpleStats/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:93:26) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SimpleStats/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:73:18) [angular]
```

It seems my understanding of navigation is completely lacking so please help. I am sure it is an easy fix but I can't seem to figure out how to navigate to the "Courses" tab by clicking my button. Navigating by cling the tabs works fine.

Here is a playground demo:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=3zF1mB&v=2

Comment: You have multiple router outlets active at a time, but while calling navigate method you are passing a path that doesn't have info which router outlet to use. You will have to use relative path to activated route here.

Comment: @Manoj Could you elaborate? I've updated the question with relative path's I've tried now but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj updated the question with a link to a playground, it contains some junk but should be straightforward enough.

Comment: Course page is already loaded in your outlet, what you need here is to switch your tab by updating selected index on tabview. You will use navigate only when you want to open a new detail page on the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use navigate method only to navigate to a new page. In your example Course is already loaded in second router outlet in second tab, so all you have to do is to change the selected index of tab view.

```
tabView.selectedIndex = 1; // will show the course page
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=3zF1mB&v=4)

Comment: Thanks, works great! Any way to get it to work with router link? E g `[nsRouterLink]="['../../courses/default']" ` ?

Comment: Thank a lot, this also/still applies for the BottomNavigation and Tab components that will replace TabView.